# I need to map one to many relationship between questions and answer entities. But questionID colum is not updating. How can I fix this?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

I used question_id as the primary key of questions table and it is a foreign key for the answers table. @JoinColumn has used for declare referencedColumnName .

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "questions")
public class Question {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long question_id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = false, length = 100)
    private String question_subjectArea;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = false, length = 1000)
    private String  fullQuestion;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn( name = "questionID", referencedColumnName = "question_id")
    List<Answer> answer = new ArrayList<>();
//Getters and setters 



@Entity
@Table(name = "answers")
public class Answer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long answer_id;

    @Column(nullable = true, unique = false, length = 100)
    private Long answer_authorID;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = false, length = 100)
    private String fullAnswer;

   //Getters and setters
```

Application.properties configuration as follows
`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create`

Comment: I don't see the reference to questionId column in your answer entity. Can you show how are you adding/updating the values.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Silverfang  `@JoinColumn( name = "questionID", referencedColumnName = "question_id")` by using this line, a column called questionID will be created in the answer entity. The problem is that questionID Colum is not updated according to the question_id in the question table.

Answer (score 0):

In our Entity class: Answer,  seems you need also define the member:  Question.

```
@ManyToOne
@JsonIgnore
@JoinColumn(name = "question", referencedColumnName = "question_id")
private Question question;
```

Comment: What do you mean by `@JoinColumn(name = "question"`. What is name = "question". Is this a name for new colum?

Comment: It's a name.  After adding this,  it can establish relation ship with the parent entity.